# What does "a" stand for in font: 0/0 a;

Tags: css, font-size, shorthand

I was referring a video tutorial where the designer used `font: 0/0 a;` for image replacement, so I get that `0` is the `font-size`, another `0` is the `line-height` but designer skips the `a` part just by saying that's an hack.

So what does that `a` exactly do there?

Comment: Relevant: [Font Shorthand Syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#propdef-font). What happens if you run the same code, minus the ` a`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

http://nicolasgallagher.com/another-css-image-replacement-technique/

> font:0/0 a – a shorthand property that zeros out the font size and
>   line-height. The a value acts as a very short font-family (an idea
>   taken from the BEM implementation of this method). The CSS validator
>   complains that using 0/0 in the shorthand font property is not valid,
>   but every browser accepts it and this appears to be an error in the
>   validator. Using font:0px/0 a passes validation but it displayed as
>   font:0/0 a in the code that the validator flags as valid.

Comment: Setting `a` only seems necessary in the shorthand notation. Longhand `font-size: 0; line-height: 0` works too it seems https://codepen.io/ryanve/pen/OzOKNd

Answer (score 15):

The `a` is a font name, and of course it's very unlikely that anyone has a font by that name installed.

It's just used to satisfy the CSS syntax, and what font the browser thinks it should use from that is not important, as it won't be used to show any text anyway.

---

If you use that on an image in order to get rid of spacing around the image, consider using `display:block` instead.